# During upload network changes, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, upload

I am developing an iOS application that the user will be able to upload a movie to vimeo. I don't know to manage the case that during the upload the network changes from wifi to 3G (or GPRS) or vise versa.

Is it possible to handle the upload correctly without pausing or killing it and not having to write "ugly" code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone handles these network handoffs seamlessly without interaction from the app. In other words, it happens at a lower level so you don't need to worry about it.